# Tomcat base URL redirection

Tags: html, tomcat

Using tomcat, how do I get a request for `http://www.mydomain.example` to redirect to `http://www.mydomain.example/somethingelse/index.jsp`? I haven't even managed to get an index.html to display from `http://mydomain.example`.

Comment: is there a reason .htaccess or isapi would not work?

Comment: @NonaUrbiz: isn't .htaccess Apache http server specific and does not work with Tomcat?

Comment: For anyone else Tomcat don't seem to recommend it see their docs - https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Running+Jenkins+behind+Apache

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Name your webapp WAR “ROOT.war” or containing folder “ROOT”

Comment: This approach causes a lot of problems when working on local and then deploying your application to multiple servers. Specially if you have multiple projects going to be deployed on different servers, and each can be ROOT on their own servers.

Answer (score 126):

You can do this: 
If your tomcat installation is default and you have not done any changes, then the default war will be `ROOT.war`. Thus whenever you will call `http://yourserver.example.com/`, it will call the `index.html` or `index.jsp` of your default WAR file. Make the following changes in your `webapp/ROOT` folder for redirecting requests to `http://yourserver.example.com/somewhere/else`:

1. Open `webapp/ROOT/WEB-INF/web.xml`,
   remove any servlet mapping with path `/index.html` or `/index.jsp`,
   and save.
2. Remove `webapp/ROOT/index.html`, if it exists.
3. Create the file `webapp/ROOT/index.jsp` with this line of content:

   ```
   <% response.sendRedirect("/some/where"); %>
   ```

   or if you want to direct to a different server,

   ```
   <% response.sendRedirect("http://otherserver.example.com/some/where"); %>
   ```

That's it.

Comment: Only needed step #2.  Tested on Tomcat 7.

Comment: The sendRedirect command was all that was needed for me.

index.jsp just contains:

<%
response.sendRedirect("/jasperserver");
%>

Comment: Don't forget to add <% and %> before any jsp scriptlet

Comment: Should be fixed now, I also fixed some other things.

Comment: Java wasn't working for me, so I used index.html with html redirection. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411538/redirect-from-an-html-page

Comment: If you need to include query parameters, you can do something like this:
`<% response.sendRedirect(request.getQueryString()!=null ? ("/some/where?" + request.getQueryString()) : "/some/where"); %>`

Answer (score 19):

Take a look at [UrlRewriteFilter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) which is essentially a java-based implementation of Apache's mod_rewrite.

You'll need to extract it into `ROOT` folder under your Tomcat's `webapps` folder; you can then configure redirects to any other context within its `WEB-INF/urlrewrite.xml` configuration file.

Comment: UrlRewriteFilter is fast and worked well for me. [the manual](http://urlrewritefilter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/doc/manual/4.0/index.html) has some great options and [this blog post](http://nematodes.org/martin/2010/02/04/301-permanent-redirect-with-tomcat-howto/) also has some good info.

Answer (score 15):

Tested and Working procedure:

Goto the file path 
`..\apache-tomcat-7.0.x\webapps\ROOT\index.jsp`

remove the whole content or declare the below lines of code at the top of the index.jsp

`<% response.sendRedirect("http://yourRedirectionURL"); %>`

Please note that in jsp file you need to start the above line with <% and end with %>

Answer (score 9):

What i did:

I added the following line inside  of ROOT/index.jsp

```
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=/somethingelse/index.jsp"/>
```

Comment: This might really screw up your analytics data, since the referral will be lost.

Comment: One small benefit of this method is it can go in index.html instead of index.jsp

Comment: @AdrianRM "it's not the way to do it", so what is the right way?

Comment: Viral Patel's and ChssPly76's are both valid answers:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/1363781/208576 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/1363685/208576

Comment: This worked for me until I have enabled HTTPS. Switched to `<% response.sendRedirect("/some/where"); %>` and it works with HTTPS now.

Answer (score 5):

In Tomcat 8 you can also use the rewrite-valve

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$         /somethingelse/index.jsp
```

To setup the rewrite-valve look here:

http://tonyjunkes.com/blog/a-brief-look-at-the-rewrite-valve-in-tomcat-8/