# Tomcat: Get short URL for Jersey based Rest Service

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, web-applications, jersey

I have a Jersey based Rest service running on a tomcat server. There is no UI, just a server that offers some rest services. Now, to access this service the URL that i have to type in is pretty long. Something like `localhost:8080/MyApp/url_pattern/classPath/method` where MyApp is the webapp that i deployed, url_pattern is the pattern that i defined in the servlet-mapping in web.xml, classPath and method being the @Path annotations for the Class and method respectively. Is it possible to shorten it such that I get rid of the MyApp and url_pattern part of this URL. Something like `localhost:8080/classPath/method`.

PS: There is just one webApp running on this server, so no point having the `MyApp` part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can remove all what you desire from the url but you can definitely remove the `MyApp` part by making it the root application for tomcat.

Answer on this related link describes it pretty well, how to set your application as the root application. So you can access your REST services without having the app name in url:

[Setting default application in tomcat 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14325171/setting-default-application-in-tomcat-7)

Content copied from the above link:

> **First Method**:
>
> first shutdown your tomcat [from the bin directory (sh shutdown.sh)]
>   then you must delete all the content of your tomcat webapps folder (rm
>   -fr *) then rename your WAR file to ROOT.war finally start your tomcat [from the bin directory (sh startup.sh)]
>
> **Second Method**:
>
> leave your war file in CATALINA_BASE/webapps, under its original name
>   - turn off autoDeploy and deployOnStartup in your Host element in the server.xml file. explicitly define all application Contexts in
>   server.xml, specifying both path and docBase. You must do this,
>   because you have disabled all the Tomcat auto-deploy mechanisms, and
>   Tomcat will not deploy your applications anymore unless it finds their
>   Context in the server.xml.
>
> Note:
>
> that this last method also implies that in order to make any change to
>   any application, you will have to stop and restart Tomcat.
>
> **Third Method**:
>
> Place your war file outside of CATALINA_BASE/webapps (it must be
>   outside to prevent double deployment). - Place a context file named
>   ROOT.xml in CATALINA_BASE/conf//. The single element in this context
>   file MUST have a docBase attribute pointing to the location of your
>   war file. The path element should not be set - it is derived from the
>   name of the .xml file, in this case ROOT.xml. See the Context
>   Container above for details.

Comment: That helped a lot. Thanks.
I managed to remove the url-pattern from the URL by specifying the URL-pattern as `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>` in web.xml