# deploy war file on Tomcat and run without project name

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, tomcat7

I 've just created war file of my  web project (JSP/Servlets).

**Project name: TestApp**

when I deply it in Tomcat 7, I run itlike that:

**localhost:8080/TestApp/** or **www.maypage.com/testApp/**

ok, everything works, but I need to run it without project name, like that:

**localhost:8080** and on hosting **www.maypage.com**

How can I do that?
thank you.

And I'm fining jsp/servlet hosting, which have that configuration option. do you know hosting like that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to access your application without using the application name, you need to deploy it as the root application. There are multiple ways to achieve it and the related answer describes it pretty well.

[Setting default application in tomcat 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14325171/setting-default-application-in-tomcat-7)

Content copied from the above link:

> **First Method:**
>
> first shutdown your tomcat [from the bin directory (sh shutdown.sh)]
>   then you must delete all the content of your tomcat webapps folder (rm
>   -fr *) then rename your WAR file to ROOT.war finally start your tomcat [from the bin directory (sh startup.sh)]
>
> **Second Method:**
>
> leave your war file in CATALINA_BASE/webapps, under its original name
>   - turn off autoDeploy and deployOnStartup in your Host element in the server.xml file. explicitly define all application Contexts in
>   server.xml, specifying both path and docBase. You must do this,
>   because you have disabled all the Tomcat auto-deploy mechanisms, and
>   Tomcat will not deploy your applications anymore unless it finds their
>   Context in the server.xml.
>
> Note:
>
> that this last method also implies that in order to make any change to
>   any application, you will have to stop and restart Tomcat.
>
> **Third Method:**
>
> Place your war file outside of CATALINA_BASE/webapps (it must be
>   outside to prevent double deployment). - Place a context file named
>   ROOT.xml in CATALINA_BASE/conf//. The single element in this context
>   file MUST have a docBase attribute pointing to the location of your
>   war file. The path element should not be set - it is derived from the
>   name of the .xml file, in this case ROOT.xml. See the Context
>   Container above for details.