# Disable adding appName to url while running war file on external tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7, spring-boot

I followed the official spring tutorial "Converting a Spring Boot JAR Application to a WAR using Maven"  [link](http://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war-maven/).

The generated war file is deployed on tomcat and is accessible at:

```
a)http://localhost:8080/${AppName}/
http://localhost:8080/gs-convert-jar-to-war-maven-0.1.0/  in case of the tutorial.
```

Which configs do I need to change to make my application directly available at

```
http://localhost:8080/  (without the appName)
```

while running my war file on tomcat?

Thanks,

Ron

Comment: Should have been more diligent with with research.
Answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413723/deploy-war-file-on-tomcat-and-run-without-project-name?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the contextRoot of your application.
There is 3 places where you can do that:

- in a file in the WAR: META-INF/context.xml
- in TOMCAT_HOME/conf/Catalina/localhost/xxx.xml
- or in server.xml file but it's better not to change it here.

In one of these places, you can add this:

```
<Context
        path="/"
        docBase="/TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/yourapp"
    />
```

Comment: Or you can just call your war file "ROOT.war "(http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html).

Comment: Yep. But, well... I prefer to configure it in a file.

Comment: Thanks Ipratlong and Dave.  Both the suggested solutions worked for me