# Tomcat8 remove unnecessary app name in the path

Tags: tomcat8

I am using Tomcat8. I deployed a war file by name admin.war.This resulted in my URL turning out to

> http://localhost:8080/admin.

Nevertheless, I want the URL to be http://localhost:8080. So I tried adding the following inside /conf/server.xml as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28269137/how-to-set-up-tomcat-context-path-for-web-application-war-file-name-is-coming).

> < Context path="" docBase="Advocatoree" debug="0" reloadable="true" >

However, this did not work. Is there an alternative?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Default web app in tomcat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5638787/default-web-app-in-tomcat)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a file called ROOT.xml in `<catalina_home>/conf/Catalina/localhost/`

And enter there the following:

```
<Context 
  docBase="yourAppName" 
  path="" 
  reloadable="true" 
/>
```

Now your application is default application on your server and you can access it with URL http://localhost:8080

Comment: I added the content as `<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Context  docBase="admin"  path=""  reloadable="true">
</Context>
` However it did not work.

Comment: try to rename your war file to root.war

Comment: I did the same and it worked. However when the name is admin.war and I place the xml with the Context tag as admin.xml inside <TOMCAT_HOME>\conf\Catalina\localhost it is not working.