# Tomcat 9 default application

Tags: tomcat, default, tomcat9

How to deploy the web app on root conditionally e.g. if I run tomcat using localhost it should give its default application which has manager etc. links but if run the same using IP it should show my application as root?

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413723/deploy-war-file-on-tomcat-and-run-without-project-name

Comment: Yes I know this but this doesn't solve my problem. I want localhost to run same as it is. But when run on ip or url it should run the other app. I have done this using redirect inside index.jsp of root. But its temporary solution while I want to use it as mask.

Comment: If you run with `localhost` or `ip`, its one and the same thing. So until and unless you want your `localhost` to point to a default `project`, there is nothing that can be done, AFAIK.

Comment: Try creating virtual hosts with tomcat