# Make my jasperserver webapp the default tomcat application

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, default, jasperserver

I installed the jasperserver on a Ubuntu Server.
Jasperserver is using a bundled tomcat.

Now I go to

```
http://domain:8080/jasperserver
```

and it works.
How can I configure tomcat, so I can go to

```
http://domain:8080
```

I tried many things (searched on the internet) but nothing works...
Tomcat version = 6

I don't have a WAR file

Answer (score 1):

Here are some suggestions:
[Default web app in tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5638787/default-web-app-in-tomcat)

Since you don't have a WAR file -- one answer suggests renaming your application to ROOT and another suggests adding this code to the server.xml file:

```
<Context path="" docBase="/usr/local/tomcat/mywebapps/myapplication">
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
</Context>
```