# Access Control Allow Origin with and without www

Tags: php, api, cors, http-headers

I built a php API with the following header:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://my-domain.de");
```

With that, I can access the api only from `https://my-domain.de` but not from `https://www.my-domain.de`

I get:

```
Origin https://www.my-domain.de is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://my-domain.de/checkin/api/generateUser.php due to access control checks.
```

How can I make this working for both: www and without www?

Comment: Why is your site itself available under two different host names to begin with? The usual approach would be to fix _that_, and have one version redirect to the other.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access-Control-Allow-Origin issue with and without www in url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370787/access-control-allow-origin-issue-with-and-without-www-in-url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add another line:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://my-domain.de");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.my-domain.de");
```

PHP doesn't support wildcard headers, you either support all domains:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Or specific as above

Comment: CORS is new to me so I don't know what's the most secure practice. My app is open to everybody and I don't want someone to use my api or run requests outside the app.

Comment: You should use a api key anyways, to make sure its properly protected