# Redirection with nginx

Tags: redirect

Using this tutorial
http://rainbow-six3.com/plesknginx/ i am trying to redirect my name.com to ip:8080 , after that setup if i acces through name.con i get an redirection loop... is there any other service to redirect? Had a lot of problems with nginx.

I want to redirect name.com to an tomcat7 application wich uses ip:8080 to get executed. Tomcat is already an headache...

Neither this helped me:

[Tomcat base URL redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363605/tomcat-base-url-redirection)
It outputs webpage not available on link: http://name.com/index.jsp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mind the words. 'Redirecting' != 'Proying'. You redirect through 301 or 302 to a publicly directly accessible resource, while you proxy to a backend, not supposed to be directly accessed.

The minimal configuration to proxy any `name.com/<whatever>` request to `<ip>:8080/<whatever>` is:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name name.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass $scheme://<ip>:8080;
    }
}
```