# how to run a servlet application with only localhost:8080 address.that means i dont want to any url patterns

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I want to run a basic servlet application using Tomcat server. While trying run application on the server,the URL pattern is `localhost:8080/myapplication/login`. 
Is there any way to run the whole application using `localhost:8080` only?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363605/tomcat-base-url-redirection

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how exactly does the application run, in which container, etc.

For example, in Tomcat, by default, the context path (`myapplication` in the question) is created because of the name of the WAR (myapplication.war)

In order to run without context path at all, rename the war into ROOT.war and deploy

Answer (score 0):

You can Define a context in the `<Tomcat>/conf/server.xml` file as follows

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" ...>
      ...
      <Context path="/" docBase="myapplication.war"/>
      ...
</Host>
```

Comment: i tried it,but its not working.application is running at localhost:8080/myapplication