# Open shift - JWS - Tomcat 8 redirect base url to application war

Tags: tomcat, openshift

I am using tomcat in JWS 3-1. I have application war "myapp.war" in

```
/opt/webserver/webapps
```

Now my url is domain.com/myapp
I want domain.com to also redirect to myapp

I was trying to follow the following link.
[Tomcat base URL redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363605/tomcat-base-url-redirection).

There is no ROOT folder in /opt/webserver/webapps.

It doesn't seem to work.

Can anyone suggest I should look in which direction?

Answer (score 0):

If there is no separate Root folder then can deploy a ROOT.war in parallel to the application war. In Root.war we can add an index.jsp which will forward to application as per the  [Tomcat base URL redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363605/tomcat-base-url-redirection).