# How to change azure web app default deployment directory from WWWROOT to WWWROOT/webapps?

Tags: java, azure, azure-web-app-service

Ho to change default deployment path from wwwroot to wwwroot/webapps in azure webapp. I am using azure pipeline to build and deploy my java .war file.

Comment: I am not sure about Azure. But usually u can create another war. With just index.jsp which will redirect to ur war. This will be static and can be pushed to ur code repository . This should be ROOT.war. This is how we do in apache tomcat. Probably u will need to have a similar approach

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62742706/open-shift-jws-tomcat-8-redirect-base-url-to-application-war

Comment: Changing the war file name is not an issue but I need to deploy it inside wwwroot/webapps even if the war file name is ROOT.war

Comment: I mean this will be another war. So there will be two war files. ROOT.war will have just one index.jsp which will redirect to your application

Comment: I understand but ROOT.war also should be inside wwwroot/webapps. In azure app service we need to deploy war inside wwwroot/webapps. Whenever I am deploying it's getting deployed inside wwwroot, that's the problem.